# CSS3 animation and background-image in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation

I have a bit of CSS3 animation in my website, and it works fine on Safari but when I run the site in Firefox, it doesn't animate. Here is the code:

```
.ad{
position:relative;
left:740px;
top:240px;
width:260px;
height:195px;
background-image:url('ad1.png');

animation:myfirst 4s; 

-webkit-animation:myfirst 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation-delay:2s;
-webkit-animation-duration:0s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes myfirst 

 {
  from {background-image:url('ad1.png')}
  to {background-image:url('ad2.png')}

 }


@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
 {
  from {background-image:url('ad1.png');}
  to {background-image:url('ad2.png');}
 }
}
```

Now I've noticed that the issue arises when the site hits the

```
 background-image:url('');
```

if I were to change these to

```
 background:color;
```

then it works, but obviously I want to use an image. I've tried adding -moz- prefixes, but it doesn't work. What am I missing? is there a way to make firefox acknowledge

```
Background-image:url('')
```

Comment: Is the image file in the same directory as this CSS file?

Comment: you can fake this in FF using different containers. each element can have 2 extra pseudo container ::before & ::after . example: http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/DJdja :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to interpolate between background images is a pretty new proposal so far, and not well supported in browsers.  Firefox doesn't implement it yet.

Comment: sad face! It's so useful though.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [latest working draft of the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/date/2015-08-14/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-image) (14 August 2015), `background-image` is defined as non animatable.

Then, Firefox is just following the spec, and the behavior of browsers which animate `background-image` is non-standard and shouldn't be relied on.

Answer (score -2):

use @-moz-keyframes
and -moz-animation
to define animation for firefox

Comment: can you paste css corresponding to firefox?