# Slideshow animation not working in Firefox 25.0

Tags: css, firefox, animation, slideshow

I'm running a CSS3 animation changing the background image of a div on my page to give a slideshow and it all works fine in Chrome and Safari with the -webkit- prefix but even though I have the unprefixed version in my code it does not want to work in Firefox. Can anyone spot anything in my code that I have missed that could cause this?

```
@keyframes slideshow
    {
0%      {background-image: url(Images/sl1.jpg);}
8.3%        {background-image: url(Images/sl2.jpg);}
16.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl3.jpg);}
25%     {background-image: url(Images/sl4.jpg);}
33.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl5.jpg);}
41.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl6.jpg);}
50%     {background-image: url(Images/sl7.jpg);}
58.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl8.jpg);}
66.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl9.jpg);}
75%     {background-image: url(Images/sl10.jpg);}
83.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl11.jpg);}
91.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl12.jpg);}
100%        {background-image: url(Images/sl1.jpg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideshow
{
0%      {background-image: url(Images/sl1.jpg);}
8.3%        {background-image: url(Images/sl2.jpg);}
16.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl3.jpg);}
25%     {background-image: url(Images/sl4.jpg);}
33.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl5.jpg);}
41.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl6.jpg);}
50%     {background-image: url(Images/sl7.jpg);}
58.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl8.jpg);}
66.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl9.jpg);}
75%     {background-image: url(Images/sl10.jpg);}
83.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl11.jpg);}
91.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl12.jpg);}
100%        {background-image: url(Images/sl1.jpg);}
}

#slideshow
{
float: right;
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image: url(Images/sl1.jpg);
animation: slideshow 60s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation: slideshow 60s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
background-size: cover;
}
```

I'm using a jquery script to input window size into the css so that the images stay within the browser size, would this affect it?

```
<script src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function windowH() {
var wH = $(window).height();

$('.sideBar, .slideshow').css({height: wH});
}

windowH();
</script>
```

Any help with this greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, animating `background-image` is not yet supported in Firefox:

[CSS3 animation and background-image in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774188/css3-animation-and-background-image-in-firefox)

You can porbably achieve the effect you're after by loading all images, then playing around with `opacity` and `z-index` to show one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't realise that it wasn't supported in Firefox, is this the only browser it isn't?

Comment: It wouldn't think it's the only one. It seems browsers are just starting to support this as it's still a new proposal.