# Moz animation showing in firebug, but not running

Tags: css, html, animation

EDIT: can get to work if I change urls to colors! But can't work out why the urls don't work in firefox.

I appreciate there are a few similar questions out there, but no answers have solved my issue.

My @keyframes animations WILL not work in Firefox, I have tried with and without prefixes, and opened firebug to check for errors.

Firstly, the code. Note, i included all the styling for the element .runner, incase it is some other part of the code stopping the animation from working.

HTML

```
  <div class="runner">
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.runner {border-radius: 40pt ;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ;
box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; 
width:49.5% ; 
height: 49.5% ; 
position: absolute ; 
top:0 ; left: 0 ; 
background: url(img/pic1.png) ;
-webkit-animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s ; 
-moz-animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s ; 
animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s}

@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
20% {background:url(img/pic1.png)}
25%, 45% {background:url(img/pic2.png)}
50%, 70% {background:url(img/pic3.png)}
75%, 95% {background:url(img/pic4.png)}
}

@-moz-keyframes slideshow {
20% {background:url(img/pic1.png)}
25%, 45% {background:url(img/pic2.png)}
50%, 70% {background:url(img/pic3.png)}
75%, 95% {background:url(img/pic4.png)}
}

@keyframes slideshow {
20% {background:url(img/pic1.png)}
25%, 45% {background:url(img/pic2.png)}
50%, 70% {background:url(img/pic3.png)}
75%, 95% {background:url(img/pic4.png)}
}
```

And this is what firebug says about .runner

```
.runner {
animation: 20s ease 2s normal none infinite slideshow;
background: url("img/pic1.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-radius: 40pt;
box-shadow: 0 0 10pt #808080;
height: 49.5%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 49.5%;
}

@-moz-keyframes slideshow {
20% {
background: url("img/pic1.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
25%, 45% {
background: url("img/pic2.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
50%, 70% {
background: url("img/pic3.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
75%, 95% {
    background: url("img/pic4.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

It then repeats this last part. Presumably because both the prefixed and non-prefixed versions are supported.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for me on FF 30. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t9c7z/)

Comment: ok so I have also got it to work using colors - but the pic URLs dont - though they do in chrome - any ideas?

Comment: I should see a demo of that in order to know. Maybe you have disabled images in Firefox, or an ad blocker blocks them, or the server doesn't serve them to firefox (user-agent content negotiation), etc.

Comment: well i don't think so - as the first image is displayed!

Comment: [OP is correct](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/8FQ2m/), but [this is a dupe.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774188/css3-animation-and-background-image-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

After further research, it appears that 'background', plus 'background-image' is not considered an object that can be animated. Why this works in chrome I am not sure.

However, stacking the images one on top of another, then using animations on the images (as opposed to background) can be used to generate the same effect, with opacity and an animation delay for each pic.