# CSS3 animation background not work on firefox

Tags: css, css-animations

Hello I have this example, it's work fine chrome and opera but not work in firefox

[check on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4x3k7Lxy/2/)

```
    body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('http://www.picz.ge/img/s2/1505/17/1/1b588904a0d2.png');
    -webkit-animation: mymove 10s;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-animation: mymove 10s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation: mymove 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {
        background: url('http://www.picz.ge/img/s2/1505/17/1/1b588904a0d2.png');
    }
    to {
        background: url('http://www.picz.ge/img/s4/1505/17/b/b2c36d72aaa6.png');
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes mymove {
    from {
        background: url('http://www.picz.ge/img/s2/1505/17/1/1b588904a0d2.png');
    }
    to {
        background: url('http://www.picz.ge/img/s4/1505/17/b/b2c36d72aaa6.png');
    }
}
@keyframes mymove {
    from {
        background: url('http://www.picz.ge/img/s2/1505/17/1/1b588904a0d2.png');
    }
    to {
        background: url('http://www.picz.ge/img/s4/1505/17/b/b2c36d72aaa6.png');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774188/css3-animation-and-background-image-in-firefox

Comment: you can use this workaround :- https://jsfiddle.net/4x3k7Lxy/4/

Comment: thanks please answer my question and I approve :)

Comment: added it as a answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a :pseudo element to add a `background-image` and change its opacity

demo - https://jsfiddle.net/4x3k7Lxy/4/