# CSS3 Animation Not Working in Firefox or Internet Explorer

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to make a simple animation in which an image fades in, fades out to another, and repeats infinitely. So far, it only works on Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox or Internet Explorer. Here's my CSS code:

```
    header #slider{
        background:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;

        -webkit-animation-name:headerAnimation;
        -webkit-animation-duration:40s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;

        -moz-animation-name:headerAnimation;
        -moz-animation-duration:40s;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;

        -ms-animation-name:headerAnimation;
        -ms-animation-duration:40s;
        -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        -ms-animation-timing-function:linear;

        -o-animation-name:headerAnimation;
        -o-animation-duration:40s;
        -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        -o-animation-timing-function:linear;

        animation-name:headerAnimation;
        animation-duration:40s;
        animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        animation-timing-function:linear;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes headerAnimation{
            0%      {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
            20%     {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
            25%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Caboose.jpg);}
            45%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Caboose.jpg);}
            50%     {background-image:url(images/slider/CivilWarReenactment_250W.jpg)}
            70%     {background-image:url(images/slider/CivilWarReenactment_250W.jpg)}
            75%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Drover_250W.jpg);}
            95%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Drover_250W.jpg);}
            100%    {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
        }

        @-moz-keyframes headerAnimation{
            0%      {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
            20%     {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
            25%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Caboose.jpg);}
            45%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Caboose.jpg);}
            50%     {background-image:url(images/slider/CivilWarReenactment_250W.jpg)}
            70%     {background-image:url(images/slider/CivilWarReenactment_250W.jpg)}
            75%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Drover_250W.jpg);}
            95%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Drover_250W.jpg);}
            100%    {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
        }

        @-ms-keyframes headerAnimation{
            0%      {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
            20%     {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
            25%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Caboose.jpg);}
            45%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Caboose.jpg);}
            50%     {background-image:url(images/slider/CivilWarReenactment_250W.jpg)}
            70%     {background-image:url(images/slider/CivilWarReenactment_250W.jpg)}
            75%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Drover_250W.jpg);}
            95%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Drover_250W.jpg);}
            100%    {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
        }

        @-o-keyframes headerAnimation{
            0%      {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
            20%     {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
            25%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Caboose.jpg);}
            45%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Caboose.jpg);}
            50%     {background-image:url(images/slider/CivilWarReenactment_250W.jpg)}
            70%     {background-image:url(images/slider/CivilWarReenactment_250W.jpg)}
            75%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Drover_250W.jpg);}
            95%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Drover_250W.jpg);}
            100%    {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
        }

        @keyframes headerAnimation{
            0%      {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
            20%     {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
            25%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Caboose.jpg);}
            45%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Caboose.jpg);}
            50%     {background-image:url(images/slider/CivilWarReenactment_250W.jpg)}
            70%     {background-image:url(images/slider/CivilWarReenactment_250W.jpg)}
            75%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Drover_250W.jpg);}
            95%     {background-image:url(images/slider/Drover_250W.jpg);}
            100%    {background-image:url(images/slider/128bridge.jpg);}
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working example using Embeded StackOverflow Snippet or at best JSFiddle (or put your code online elsewhere) so we could test it?

Comment: You can see this code in action on the following website: http://temp.srrl-rr.com/

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989076/5208897)

> According to the [candidate recommendation spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-css3-background-20140909/#background-image) (9 September 2014),
>   `background-image` is defined as non animatable.
>
> Then, Firefox is just following the spec, and the behavior of browsers
>   which animate `background-image` is non-standard and shouldn't be relied
>   on.

Maybe try to implement something like this - [Simple jQuery image crossfade](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The animation is working across all the major web browsers now.

Answer (score 0):

`background-image` transition is supported natively by Chrome, Opera and Safari, but not In Firefox or IE.
Your best option would be to either use pseudo elements, or `<div>`'s, and animate the opacity.

Comment: Or a spritesheet with animated `background-position`.